# Why does inherited protected operator=() has public access

Tags: c++

An overloaded operator `=` declared as protected is publicly accessible for the child classes inheriting the parent class as public.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A(char c) : i(c) {}
    char i;

protected:
    A& operator=(const A& rdm) {
        std::cout << "accessing operator=()" << std::endl;
        i = 'x';
        return *this;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(char c) : A(c) {}
};


int main(int ac, char** av) {

    B a('a');
    B b('b');

    std::cout << "a.i == " << a.i << std::endl;

    a = b;

    std::cout << "a.i == "<< a.i << std::endl;
}
```

No error at compilation:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o test_operator ~/test_operator.cpp
$ ./test_operator
a.i == a
accessing operator=()
a.i == x
```

Using A directly wont compile. Any other operator overload than `operator=()` wont compile.
Tested with g++ 4.4.7 and 7.3.0 with both c++98 and c++17.

Why is `operator=()` publicly accessible in this case?

Comment: And that implicit operator calls the base class operator.

Comment: The Rule of Three strikes again.

Comment: Would you make it protected, would the compiler fail to compile but give a hint about what's happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an implicit copy assignment operator in `B` with `public` access.

From [the C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.copy#18):

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted ([[dcl.fct.def]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.def)). The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy constructor or a user-declared destructor. The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator for a class X will have the form
>
> ```
> X& X::operator=(const X&)
> ```
>
> if
>
> — each direct base class `B` of `X` has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type `const B&`, `const volatile B&` or `B`, and
>
> — for all the non-static data members of `X` that are of a class type `M` (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type `const M&`, `const volatile M&` or `M`.
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator will have the form
>
> ```
> X& X::operator=(X&)
> ```

In other words, your code behaves as though you had:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B(char c) : A(c) {}
    B& operator=(B const& rhs) { A::operator==(rhs); return *this; }
};
```

---

Here's updated version of your that demonstrates the behavior of the implicitly declared copy assignment operator function. It demonstrates that `B` does not inherit `A`'s copy assignment operator.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A(char c) : i(c) {}
    char i;

protected:
    A& operator=(const A& rdm) {
        std::cout << "accessing A::operator=()" << std::endl;
        i = 'x';
        return *this;
    }
};

class X
{
   public:
      X& operator=(X const& rhs)
      {
        std::cout << "accessing X::operator=()" << std::endl;
        return *this;
      }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(char c) : A(c) {}
    X x;
};


int main(int ac, char** av) {

    B a('a');
    B b('b');

    std::cout << "a.i == " << a.i << std::endl;

    a = b;

    std::cout << "a.i == "<< a.i << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a.i == a
accessing A::operator=()
accessing X::operator=()
a.i == x
```

The implicitly declared/defined copy assignment operator behaves as though we had:

```
B& operator=(B const& rhs)
{
   A::operator==(rhs);
   this.x = rhs.x;
   return *this;
}
```

This is in keeping with what the [standard says](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.copy#28):

> The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a non-union class `X` performs memberwise copy/move assignment of its subobjects. The direct base classes of `X` are assigned first, in the order of their declaration in the *base-specifier-list*, and then the immediate non-static data members of `X` are assigned, in the order in which they were declared in the class definition.

Comment: A class X with its own `operator=` displaying a message, and a private member of class X in B, could help to understand that it's not just the inherited operator: https://ideone.com/pJRpNP

Comment: Would you know where the default method implementation is specified in the standard?

Comment: @Jean, you can find it at https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.copy#28.

Comment: Oh, right. I was looking for the item 29 actually! Thanks for your answer.